# Make a child absolute overflow on a max-w parent

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm creating a scrollable child and I want that initially it starts based on parent wrapper and when you scroll it the elements will overflow the parent wrapper.

```
<div class="flex justify-center w-full">
   <div class="max-w-[500px]">
      <section class="w-full overflow-visible">
         <div class="scrollable-wrapper w-full">
            <div class="scrollable-content flex gap-x-4 snap-mandatory overflow-x-auto">
               <!-- Child Elements Example -->
               <div class="w-[300px] h-[100px]">Lorem Ipsum</div>
               <div class="w-[300px] h-[100px]">Lorem Ipsum</div>
               <div class="w-[300px] h-[100px]">Lorem Ipsum</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

(Please note that all measurements I gave are purely for giving an example)

I tried to move the section out of the max-w parent but also if I try to padding/margin this wont work.

By the way if this is solvable within a max-w parent would help me a lot. If not I'll try to search another solution (like to append this absolutely in the wrapper).

Comment: I just solved this taking out the scrollable-wrapper from the max-w parent and creating a custom px function `calc((100vw - { MAX-W }) / 2)` inside scrollable content